# extract key value pairs from R dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns. An ID column and a character column containing key value pairs delimited by semicolon.

```
   ID | KeyValPairs
    1 | "zx=1; ds=4; xx=6"
    2 | "qw=5; df=2"
    . | ....
```

I want to turn this into a dataframe with three columns

```
    ID | Key | Val
     1 | zx  | 1
     1 | ds  | 4
     1 | xx  | 6
     2 | qw  | 5
     2 | df  | 2
```

There is no fixed number of key value pairs in the KeyValPairs column, and no closed set of possible keys. I have been goofing around with solutions that involve looping and reinserting into an empty dataframe, but it is not working properly and I am told I should avoid loops in R.

Comment: data.frame or text file? `dput( head( myData ) )` would be nice in case of the former.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tidyr and dplyr approach:

**tidyr**

```
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
s <- separate(df, KeyValPairs, 1:3, sep=";")
m <- melt(s, id.vars="ID")
out <- separate(m, value, c("Key", "Val"), sep="=")
na.omit(out[order(out$ID),][-2])
#   ID Key Val
# 1  1  zx   1
# 3  1  ds   4
# 5  1  xx   6
# 2  2  qw   5
# 4  2  df   2
```

**dplyrish**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(KeyValPairs = strsplit(as.character(KeyValPairs), "; ")) %>% 
  unnest(KeyValPairs) %>% 
  separate(KeyValPairs, into = c("key", "val"), "=")
#courtesy of @jeremycg
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2), KeyValPairs = structure(c(2L, 1L
), .Label = c(" qw=5; df=2", " zx=1; ds=4; xx=6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"KeyValPairs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: The unnest function in tidyr did the trick. I could not get the first suggestion to work, but it looks to me like the seperate function needs to know the exact number of maximum splits to make new columns from. You assume 3, but I don't know that in my scenario

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution, just to use `tstrsplit`:

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, .(key = unlist(strsplit(as.character(KeyValPairs), ";"))), by = ID
          ][, c("Val", "Key") := tstrsplit(key, "=")
            ][, key := NULL][]
#   ID Val Key
#1:  1  zx   1
#2:  1  ds   4
#3:  1  xx   6
#4:  2  qw   5
#5:  2  df   2
```

Comment: I made some edits (without checking if I broke something) if you don't mind.

Comment: I missed the final `[]` and so the result wasn't printed. A poster commented that the solution didn't work for him (don't know why) and so I made it more "verbose" and made sure that at the end the result was printed. Anyway, now it's good.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe also a case for `{splitstackshape}` from @AnandaMahto:

```
df <- read.table(sep = "|", header = TRUE, text = '
ID | KeyValPairs
1 | "zx=1; ds=4; xx=6"
2 | "qw=5; df=2"')
library(splitstackshape)
setNames(
   cSplit(cSplit(df, 2, ";", "long"), 2, "="), 
   c("id", "key", "val")
)
# id key val
# 1:  1  zx   1
# 2:  1  ds   4
# 3:  1  xx   6
# 4:  2  qw   5
# 5:  2  df   2
```